# jQuery window.location.hash troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, location

I have a one-page scroll type of site that uses a scroll-snapping plugin to snap from one section to the next. When each section is scrolled to, the hash changes (#1, #2, #3, etc).

I want to use the hash change to trigger an animation. So when testing the function I wrote, it only works when the page is refreshed. I can't post the site itself because it is local, but here is the code.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Trigger an animation based on hash location/URL
function hashChange() {
    alert("hashChange works!");
};
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash === '#3') {
    hashChange();
};

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

=======

---

UPDATE:

This is my updated code. But now it runs on every hash change (#1, #2, #3, #4).

```
function hashChange() {
    alert("hashChange works!");
};
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChange);
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash === '#3') {
    hashChange();
};
```

Does anyone know how to specify it? Also it is a one-page scroll that snaps to sections as you scroll. The hash changes as you scroll from section, but it doesn't trigger the alert I wrote.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an event listener for the `hashchange` event.

In your case:

```
function hashChange() {
  alert('hashChange works!');
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChange);
```

Comment: This definitely works, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/azefpgz6/. Check your console in case you have errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Strange, I don't see any problems in the console. The function is triggered for every section when I use the navigation, but not when the hash change is activated by scrolling... Strange

Comment: I thought the problem might be that the event doesn't get fired if the hash is changed programmatically... but no: http://jsfiddle.net/qe3hoLuq/2/